# Oracle Buffer Pool TARGET_SIZE is different from CURRENT_SIZE, but RESIZE_STATE is STATIC

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

According to [the documentation for `V$BUFFER_POOL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_1062.htm#REFRN30032), `TARGET_SIZE` shows that target size when resizing, but should be the same as `CURRENT_SIZE` if `RESIZE_STATE` is `STATIC`.

However, on one of our databases `TARGET_SIZE` is much larger than `CURRENT_SIZE` (which is currently far too low), but `RESIZE_STATE` is `STATIC`. How can this state come about?

Comment: Does querying `v$memory_resize_ops` and `dba_hist_memory_resize_ops` reveal anything interesting?

Comment: It shows an error shrinking DEFAULT buffer cache, but weirdly not to the current size.